# Integrating paypal with sql database

Tags: mysql, paypal

I have been searching around for an answer to this, but I havent come across anything that answers my question. I have a MySQL database that contains data for various items and a function that triggers the results via an option form. Id like to pull pricing in using the same method, and pass the options associated with the selected ID's to a checkout.

My question is, how much of this can / will the PayPal button do, and what configuration (within my PayPal account / their apps) do I need to be looking at to have it achieve this? In other words, my process needs to be something like >

user selects option > relevant pricing is displayed > field data associated with that ID is stored before the user hits submit > user hits submit / buy now / paypal button > information is passed to the paypal checkout.

How much of this is already done in some shape or form via the PayPal options, and how much am I going to have to code? It seems like options are configured on the page in the demo implementations, then it just passes the data into the cart.

Any ideas? thanks all.

Comment: So just to clarify, you want to post items stored in a DB to Website Payments Standard? Encrypted or unencrypted?

Comment: @Machavity. Encrypted. i actually figured this out. For anyone that wants comes across this and is looking to do something similar, PayPal can generate an API key that allows you to pass items through to their checkout. You need a cart / somewhere to store the result before passing it along and cannot do it through their configurable buttons (as far as I could work out).